# Playframework evolutions

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

In Playframework there are evolutions. Problem is that by default it always rewrites `1.sql` file under `evolutions/default/` so that after execution all tables are dropped and data is lost. Is there a way to generate evolutions as migrations in PHP Symfony2 framework when only changes are applied(for example new fields added with `ALTER` statement)!?

P.S. I am using MySQL database

Comment: It was discussed several times on the StackOverflow and also Play's google group (check link from previous comment)